# Postgresql insert into table with case

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, sql-insert

About the table and columns:

- PostgreSQL15.

Table name: customer

Columns:

```
customer_id integer,
store_id smallint,
first_name character varying(45),
last_name character varying(45),
email character varying(50),
address_id samllint,
activebool boolean,
create_date date,
last_update timestamp without time zone,
active integer
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHHIL.png)

I want to insert a new column called `customer_class`, then fill it with a `CASE` syntax.

```
CASE 
    WHEN (customer id <= 100) THEN 'Premium' 
    WHEN (customer_id between 100 and 200) THEN 'Plus'
    ELSE 'Other'
END
```

I have just learned about the `CASE` statement. I haven't learned `COALESCE, CAST, NULLIF`, views, import and export.

What I have tried so far:

```
ALTER TABLE customer
ADD COLUMN customer_class VARCHAR(100);

INSERT INTO customer (customer_class, store_id, first_name, last_name, email, address_id, activebool, create_date, last_update,active)
SELECT 
CASE WHEN (customer_id>=0 and customer_id<=100) THEN 'Premium'
     WHEN (customer_id between 100 and 200) THEN 'Plus'
     ELSE 'other'
     END AS customer_class,
     store_id AS store_id,
     first_name AS first_name,
     last_name AS last_name,
     email AS email,
     address_id AS address_id,
     activebool AS activebool,
     create_date AS create_date,
     last_update AS last_update,
     active AS active
FROM customer
```

The result: some of the values in customer_class returned NULL even if they are <=100

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clILv.png)

Comment: So you already have data in the table and you just want to add a column? looks like you need an update statement not an insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A brief explanation of why some of your customer_class returns NULL. You just insert a duplication of existing data. But old data, with NULLs, still persist in db. So, use the update statement like this

```sql
update customer 
set customer_class=CASE WHEN (customer_id>=0 and customer_id<=100) THEN 'Premium'
     WHEN (customer_id between 100 and 200) THEN 'Plus'
     ELSE 'other'
     END
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just to confirm, should I use this update statement right after adding the customer_class column?